# Filtering listbox using textbox, while the listbox is filled using File Names

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, textbox, listbox

I am unable to find a solution to this on here as it is filled in differently from how other questions similair to this have asked.

Basically, I'd like to filter a listbox with Dvd Names in it.

How Listbox is filled:

```
private void AdminShop_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\DvDShop\\DvdNames\\");

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            lbxDvd.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
        }

    }
```

So far in textChanged,when I input any text in the textbox, the listbox turns blank, but when I delete anything in the textbox, it fills back up again with all the entries. I feel like I am missing a simple issue here.

TextChanged:

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\DvDShop\\DvdNames\\");

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) == false)
        {
            lbxDvd.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                if (file.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    lbxDvd.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
                }
            }

        }
        else if (txtSearch.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            lbxDvd.Items.Clear();

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                lbxDvd.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help with my small issue would be appreciated!

Comment: Give an example of your file name and what you are entering in textbox

Comment: Probably it should be `string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file); if (filename.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.Trim()`....

Comment: @Rahul Here's some pictures to show the issue: 1: https://i.gyazo.com/c8f8e24161dbfc15a25896c940ba1f51.png   2: https://i.gyazo.com/a5211ac954009b5b7ec0b38742f0bb98.png 3: https://i.gyazo.com/f2364866becaa2376dfc7ac0d2b9d051.png

Comment: Anyway, I think this is very unefficient. You should use a ObservableCollection and use a filter instead of add/remove items from the listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the full path to check if it Starts With it, try this code:

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\DvDShop\\DvdNames\\");

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) == false)
    {
        lbxDvd.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file); 
            if (filename.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.Trim()))
            {
                lbxDvd.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
            }
        }

    }
    else if (txtSearch.Text.Trim() == "")
    {
        lbxDvd.Items.Clear();

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            lbxDvd.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats it! It works perfectly now! Thank you so much Pikoh!

Answer (score 1):

You are checking against `Directory.GetFiles()` which returns full path. Rather get the filename and check like

```
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
          string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            if (filename.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.Trim()))
            {
                lbxDvd.Items.Add(filename);
            }
        }
```